# App initiates the In App Purchase process in a non-standard manner

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Apple has rejected my application with following reason:
"app initiates the In App Purchase process in a non-standard manner.

Instead of displaying the item description first and asking for a login after the user taps OK, the app asks for the login first, which is the incorrect order. "

I have checked my code, but it's the same as in my other application, where in-app purchase works fine. Then I've changed bundle ID and productID (set the bundle ID from my other app) and it worked fine!

It's very odd, I think. Anybody had this problem? Can you help me?

UPD:

In the debugger I see this error:

"Unexpected exception during finish transaction: Cannot finish a purchasing transaction"

It happens at this moment in code:

```
    @try 
    {
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction]; 
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Unexpected exception during finish transaction: %@", exception);
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your error message would seem to state that you're trying to finish a transaction whose state is `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing`.

You should check the state of the transaction via `[transaction transactionState]` first to ensure the transaction is either:

> SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed
>
> SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased
>
> SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored

See the Apple Documentation for further clarification:

> Your application should call this method from a transaction observer that received a notification from the payment queue. Calling finishTransaction: on a transaction removes it from the queue. Your application should call finishTransaction: only after it has successfully processed the transaction and unlocked the functionality purchased by the user.
>
> Calling finishTransaction: on a transaction that is in the SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing state throws an exception.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it doesn't work. I think, there are one another transaction, which [SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] tries to finish. I don't know where it comes from... I'll resolve my issue next way: I'll re-create my app on itunesconnect.apple.com with new bundleID. I hope, it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I resolved this problem. It is very strange, but re-creating my game in itunesconnect.apple.com helps me.

Comment: Are you saying that you deleted and recreated the IAP content ?